# Load resource file (json) in kotlin js

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js-interop, kotlin-js, kotlin2js

Given this code, where should I place the file.json to be able to be found in the runtime?

```
// path: src/main/kotlin/Server.kt
fun main() {
  val serviceAccount = require("file.json")
}
```

I tried place it under src/main/resources/ without luck. I also use Gradle to compile kotlin to js with `kotlin2js` plugin.

Comment: Will this code run on the server side (NodeJS) or on the client side?

Comment: @AlexanderEgger server side, so the path is (easier) guaranteed

Comment: using gradle only wont help, use the kotlin-frontend-plugin as well, locate you file.json in the resources folder and watch the magic happen

Comment: you need something like `json-loader` plugin for webpack to load json with code

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the Kotlin compiler puts the created JS file (say `server.js`) into the default location at `build/classes/kotlin/main` and the resource file (`file.json`) into `build/resources/main`.

And you are running `server.js` by executing `node build/classes/kotlin/main/server.js`

According to the NodeJS documentation:

*Local modules and JSON files can be imported using a relative path (e.g. ./, ./foo, ./bar/baz, ../foo) that will be resolved against the directory named by __dirname (if defined) or the current working directory.*
(https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id)

In our case `__dirname` is `build/classes/kotlin/main`

So the correct require statement is:

```
val serviceAccount = js("require('../../../resources/main/file.json')")
```

or if `require` is defined as a Kotlin function like in the question

```
val serviceAccount = require("../../../resources/main/file.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just use `js("require('./file.json')")` if you do not have import for the `require` function in Kotlin. The result will be `dynamic`, so you may cast it to `Map`.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/js.html

Comment: How will solve the issue? I see that either `require("file.json")` or `js("require('file.json')")` will generate the same javascript code: `require('file.json')`. The problem still remains that the file.json cannot be found in the path. To be precice with the exception: `Error: Cannot find module 'file.json'`

Comment: I guess the `./file.json` may help then